# Seeking advice on de-bloating asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I’m new to .net, though I’ve been writing in classic asp for years. I know it’s time to make the change, but I can’t stand how bloated the HTML becomes.

For example, a simple menu using a web.sitemap and  adds over 100 lines of JavaScript and HTML. A simple form with server-side validation adds in masses of ugly JavaScript. And a basic table of data using GridView adds in a ViewState that makes my eyes water.

Call me a purest, though I don’t like sending data to the browser unless it’s needed. And I don’t need a form-riddled menu when a simple unordered list of links will suffice.

So, set in my ways, am I destined to forgo the benefits of the Framework entirely by insisting on writing my own, cleaner code for everything? Or am I missing the point?

As a brief aside I’m a big fan of Campaign Monitor, a newsletter distribution company. They’ve written an elegant and comprehensive user-interface in .net without a single ViewState or bizarre .net-mangeled ID reference. Even the Sign Up form on their website (/signup.aspx) is as clean as a whistle. What’s their secret?

I hope I not the only one. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try ASP.NET MVC or one of the other MVC web frameworks for .NET

Answer (score 4):

If your GridView doesn't need it, then turn ViewState off for it.

Also, please edit your question to say what version of .NET you're using. Some of this gets better, and some does not. You might also want to try VS2010 beta 1, and complain about anything it doesn't fix.

Another idea would be to go on treating ASP.NET like it's classic ASP. Do it exactly the way you're used to, but do it with the idea in mind that there's about 10 years of development work that's gone into solving some of the problems of classic ASP. Once you actually *hit* one of those problems, find out if ASP.NET has solved it, and how.

For instance, I have a hard time believing you enjoy writing FOR loops to generate table rows. If you get tired of that, learn to use a Repeater control, or a DataList control, or even the old DataGrid control. If you turn ViewState off on those, I think you may find the generated HTML to be acceptable, and you'll find it a lot easier to generate tables and other structures that repeat based on repeating data.

Answer (score 2):

You can opt-out of much of that bloat by not using all the out-of-the-box controls that come with it but I prefer the MVC route that activa suggested

Answer (score 2):

Here is my list:

- Keep the use of asp controls to minimum
- Turn off Viewstate when it's not need
- If you don't want the JavaScript associated with Client Side Validation (with ASP.NET Validation) set the EnableClientScript to False
- Use asp:literal instead of asp:Label

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it seems to be that everyone is bashing webforms at the minute for the reasons you have outlined above. HTML heavy Controls, ViewState, no control over ClientIDs all seem to cause an issue with people.

However let is be said that you can use asp.net (webforms) and produce some decent applications.

Control of html is yours through httpModules and httpHandlers and some of the issues mentioned above are fixed in [asp.net 4.0](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet40/)

I just listened to a great [podcast](http://herdingcode.com/?p=183) comparing MVC and webforms. Its in the area you are asking about. Also check out [this blogpost](http://blog.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2009/04/23/I-Spose-Irsquo3bll-Just-Say-It-Still-Waiting-For-a-GOOD-Reason-to-Learn-MVC.aspx) by a dotNetNuke regarding the good asp.net code and why people should take a breath before converting everything to mvc.

Having said that I've tried Asp.net MVC and it is awesome. I'd probably look at dotNetNukes code to as its a mature asp.net product.

Comment: Thank you for your balance – listened to the podcast you recommended and was glad to hear both sides of the story. Sounds like I've stumbled into a contentious subject!

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you do want to use these newfangled server controls, check out the css friendly control adapters. They clean up much of the bloat.

For client IDs the key thing to remember is to let the framework handle them. If you need to get an element on the client side, remember to emit the control's ClientID property into your script.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a template system and am very happy with it. Basically write an http handler for .html files and put tokens in the html files that regex could find in one sweep and inject any stuff. (google template c# for more info).

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the supposedly cool new features of ASP.NET for a little while.  I also didn't like most of them.  I felt constrained to work within the limitations of the common paradigms Microsoft had dreamed, even though I new how easy it would be to produce the HTML and JavaScript myself to do specifically what I wanted to do without having to learn how to jump through the hoops of so many new Microsoft-specific idiosyncrasies.

Anyway, I stopped using the parts of ASP.NET I didn't like on new code I've been writing lately.  When I first started using ASP.NET, nothing in the MSDN documentation jumped out at me about how to avoid such complications, so I posted a couple "Hello, World" at http://www.agalltyr.com/rawaspdotnet.html to help spread the heretical word.  I couldn't care less if it's the latest cool technology or the recommended technique.  It's a reliable and reasonably efficient tool I can use to do my work.

Oh, and I'm not in the mood to learn ASP.NET MVC either.  That's just more idiosyncrasies.  Give me a language (C#) and a framework (.NET), and I'll design my own abstraction, thank you.